# From fundamental solution to differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

There are various techniques to find the fundamental solutions for a given linear ordinary differential equation (ode). I am interested in reverse engineering; to find a differential equation from a set of fundamental solution. However, it is easy for constant coefficients using corresponding characteristic equation but how about non constant coefficients.

For example, if we have following third order differential equation:
   $y'''+p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=0$
and $\left \{1,exp(x^2), log(x) \right \}$ is a set of fundamental solution. How should I find $p(x), q(x)$ and $r(x)$?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: i would plug in the solution in the given equation

Comment: Yes, indeed this is a naive way to get the solution. I am looking for some other way which does not require a great deal of calculations. As in case for constant coefficients, characteristic equation helps you out to get the desired equation without doing a great deal of work. I would be grateful if you could mention some similar technique which does not require plugging in solution each time to get a new equation. Something like, substituting all the solutions at once. Thanks!